# Problems with the div not sticking to the top of the page when scrolled to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the div "button_tray" stick to the top of the page when scrolled by. the whole page looks like this so you can get a better idea of what i'm trying to do: http://tinypic.com/r/n6cnte/8

It seems to be working when I pasted bits of code needed for this to work into jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/641/

So I really have no idea what is it here making it not work.

Appreciate the help.

HTML:

```
<doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo(stylesheet_url)?>"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="sticky.js"></script>
        </head>
            <body>
                <div id="main_img"></div>

                <div id="button_tray">
                    Sample 1
                    Sample 2
                    Sample 3
                </div>

            <div id="content">
```

part of CSS:

```
#button_tray {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #373737;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: orange;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
}

#button_tray.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

JS:

```
var $window = $(window);
            $stickyEl = $('#button_tray');
            var elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;
            $window.scroll(function() {
                var windowTop = $window.scrollTop();
                $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', windowTop > elTop);
            });
```

Comment: _What_ is not working? I've inserted some sample text before `#button_tray` and cannot face any problem. Div is perfectly sticking to the top when scrolling down.

Comment: does Wordpress have anything to do with it since I'm building a custom theme for Wordpress?

Comment: So the problem occurs only on your (local/remote) server but not in fiddle? Have you checked JS-Console output? JQuery properly loaded?

Comment: Look like your JS code didn't run. Make sure that your JS code run

Comment: or write #button_tray in css instead of #button_tray.sticky

Comment: how do i make JS code run... :/

Comment: i created a class "sticky" in JS thats why #button_tray.sticky

Comment: and yes. the problem only occurs on my local server...

Comment: If this is your actual code `<script type="text/javascript" src="sticky.js"></script>`, that won't work in WordPress. You need to use the `bloginfo` function like in your stylesheet `href` - so it would be something like `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/sticky.js` (provided your sticky.js file is in a js folder).

Comment: i've been thinking if the link is incorrect

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"
   src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/yourScript.js"></script>

Answer (score -3):

Div tags are stacked on each other from top to bottom without CSS.

Probably, there is a syntax error. I believe instead of using #button_tray, try using .button_tray

Comment: Obviously, you did not even get the difference between id and class selector.